# Where and how do I start to make an online text editor like that of Quora?

Tags: javascript, jquery, editor

I know a bit of jQuery and Javascript along with Django for the backend. I am interested in building an editor somewhat like the editor of Quora. I have read that their editor is made with a DIV whose content-editable property is set to True. However, I am confused as to what material to study in order to understand how it works with text formatting and media upload. Although I like Quora's editor the StackExchange editor is pretty nice too. I think I'm not gonna be able to implement something so advanced but I need to start somewhere.

In short, can anyone point me to an article or tutorial which deals with coders trying to make an editor from scratch or customize from open source?

Answer (score 1):

contentEditable was added by Microsoft in IE5. This feature allow to change innerHTML of any element. good place to start would be [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla) and [many](https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor) [open-source](https://github.com/bootstrap-wysiwyg/bootstrap3-wysiwyg) [implementation](https://github.com/summernote/summernote) of [wysiwyg](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce) [widgets](https://github.com/mycolorway/simditor) [available](https://github.com/kindsoft/kindeditor) [on](https://github.com/samclarke/SCEditor) [github](https://github.com/liferay/alloy-editor).

**Short explanation**

- Start with empty div.
- Set contentEditable to true.
- Add button that would act as emphasis functionality.
- Learn about [text selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection).
- If button clicked and text was selected, wrap that text with span tag  with emphasis styling css (or class).
- Profit.